# Set Repeating Alarm

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-calendar

I am new to alarm functionality. I am developing a application of alarm. In which i am able to set the alarm. And when the alarm rings the customize note comes on the pop up window.
My code is :

Main.java

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AlarmMainActivity extends Activity {    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 40);

        //Create a new PendingIntent and add it to the AlarmManager
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,12345, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

AlarmRecieverActivity.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AlarmReceiverActivity extends Activity {
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alarm);

        callStop();

       playSound(this, getAlarmUri());        
    }

    private void playSound(Context context, Uri alert) {
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, alert);
            final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0) {
                mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
             System.out.println("OOPS");
        }
    }

    //Get an alarm sound. Try for an alarm. If none set, try notification, 
    //Otherwise, ringtone.
    private Uri getAlarmUri() {
        Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        if (alert == null) {
            alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            if (alert == null) {
            alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
            }
        }
        return alert;
    }

    private void callStop(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Medicine Alert");
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("ABC");
    alertDialogBuilder.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                   
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
                    finish();
        } //end onClick.
    }); // end alertDialog.setButton.
    alertDialogBuilder.show();  
    }
}
```

And the requirement is that: Now i want to set multiple alarms.

The alarm should set for the next 5 to 6 days as the parameter passed.

User can edit alarm, delete alarm and delete all alarms at once.

What changes should i do in code and what should i add more. Please suggest.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [`AlarmManager.setRepeating`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29).

Comment: Thank you for the help. but i am not getting the way how to set repeat alarm for 3 or 4 or 5 days. And how to edit the alarms which are set.